# Flutter : How to put if statement inside onPressd using a materialButton

Tags: flutter

Iwant to put an if condition which check if a textField is empty. If the textField is not empty, a snackBar shows signup successful.
How can I put an if statement before `setState()`?

```
onPressed: () {

setState(() {
  EmailController.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
});

showInSnackBar("SignUp succesfull");}
```

Comment: How this question is related to java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      EmailController.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
      if(!_validate) showInSnackBar("SignUp succesfull");
    });
}
```

or

```
onPressed: () {
        EmailController.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
          if(!_validate) showInSnackBar("SignUp succesfull");
        setState(() {});
    }
```

Comment: Also the ternary operator is redundant here. You can just assign isEmpty to _validate.

Comment: if(EmailController.text.isNotEmpty) showInSnackBar("SignUp succesfull");
setState(() {});
should have work too

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed:(){
   if(emailcontroller.text.length != 0){
       // show snack bar
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a one-liner [ternary operator](https://dart-tutorial.com/conditions-and-loops/ternary-operator-in-dart/):

```
onPressed: () =>  EmailController.text.isEmpty == false ? setState(() => _validate = true) : {},
```

`{}` is to instruct to do nothing.